# Storyboard for java app

Tags: java, storyboard

have the task of creating the story board for a Java desktop application . I was wondering if there are some tools to create storyboards which as close as possible will look like a Java Swing application . I need to draw it well ( and close enough to the app i want to make ) so that I can use it to sell the idea to my investers .

Last time I had used InkScape to do the same . I know I can use Power Point and Paint but i am just wondering if by any chance there is something that can mimic the UI of Java well.

*PS:* *I hope the questions isnt closed fast without me getting any good leads!*

Comment: Well given the fact that you can use different look and feels there are a lot of possible Java UIs and you could also make a look and feel that mimics your presentation ;)

Comment: @Thomas haha maybe true . Anyway I will have to do that if i get no answers to this questions :P